# Vim showing "..." and locking when searching for a file without a plugin

Tags: search, vim, path

I am trying to learn vim, and am trying to do so without any plugins. Tried following a few accounts on how to set up a fuzzy search, but I am a little stuck.

What I have in my vimrc as it concerns searching files, and how I understand it to be working is below:

```
" search down into subfolders/provides tab-completion for all file-related tasks
set path+=**

" display all matching files when we tab complete
set wildmenu
```

What is happening:

1. I type `:find filena` at the bottom of the editor
2. Hit `tab` to see some autocomplete action
3. What shows up instead at the bottom is something like this: `:find filena...` and the editor seems to be in a frozen state. I hit `Ctrl-c` and am able to get out of it.

If I type in the complete `filename` and hit `<enter>` it works no problem, finding the file immediately. But the autocomplete is not functioning as I would expect. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Some more info if it might be helpful:

1. When I `<enter>` `:set path`, this is returned: `path=.,/usr/include,,,**` which should be fine from what I have read.
2. Other post looking to implement a fuzzy search without plugins. Have tried a couple of other ways, but with the same behavior: [Opening files in Vim using Fuzzy Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372307/opening-files-in-vim-using-fuzzy-search)
3. The path on the machine I am working on (a bit of mess I admit, but not sure if it might be the culprit): `/Users/NJJJ/bin:/Users/NJJJ/.rbenv/shims:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: From what I saw, vim searches from your current position, so if you're at `/` for example, it will fuzzy-search on your whole system... So it really depends where you're searching from

Comment: Yes, absolutely right, thanks! I forgot to check where I was launching vim from, and that was costly. Fixed when that was addressed. That said, will probably use a plugin going forward given the interference Ben Knoble mentions below.

Answer (score 1):

Do *not* `set path+=**`.

There’s a whole bunch of reasons, but it boils down to

1. You hurt the value of commands like `gf` (here’s a [list with more](https://github.com/tpope/vim-apathy))
2. You can cause very slow complete for `:find` and friends, as you’ve noticed.

This is because is performing a recursive directory walk of the entire system (or at least the system under your current directory). This is heavier than it needs to be.

Comment: Thanks for response! The link you posted seems to suggest going with a plugin for searches to avoid the interference you mentioned. Had no idea the interference would be an issue, but makes sense.