# vim fuzzy finder subdirectory search?

Tags: vim

Is there anyway to ask Fuzzy Finder plugin for VIM search subdirectory as well? It appears to me that no matter what mode I am in, it either search current directory, or I have to be explicit on subdirectory name for it to dive in.

Another plugin folks here mentioned in fuzzy finder textmate plugin. Unfortunately, this plugin doesn't work with current version of vim-fuzzy finder, or so it appears to me.

Any suggestions?

TIA

Oliver

Comment: This probably belongs on superuser.com

Comment: It is true fuzzy finder textmate does not work with FuzzyFinder 3.x, but it does work with 2.22.3, a relatively recent version of FuzzyFinder. You will not notice the difference. I highly recommend trying it, you will not be disappointed. See: http://github.com/jamis/fuzzyfinder_textmate/network

Also see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894614/vim-fuzzyfinder-usage-tips-gotchas-how-can-one-make-use-of-this-plugin/1897075#1897075

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `**` to have it recurse down directories.

Comment: That works pretty well. I have been trying out Command-T but it doesn't quite work like fuzzyfinder textmate did. Doing something like this would work in FuzzyFinder 3.x: `:FufFile **/somedir/**/*partial*py`

Answer (score 5):

I use tag mode provided by fuzzyfinder to simulate behavior of Textmate. in short, generate an extra tags file with file's base name as tag, then you can locate any files in the tags file directly by file's base name.

The only drawback is you need to update the file tags file, this is a script for that.

I have been using this method for several months and it works almost perfect.

I summarize my method [here](http://linsong.github.com/2010/03/20/super-finder-in-vim.html)

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to contribute to jamessan's answer. 
It is true that using **/ before your search will do a recursive search in your directory. However, I've found that it's more useful to have the recursive search enabled by default.

In order to do that, you can add ** to your mapping (mine is ])  (you have to escape the * otherwise it won't work)

```
map <leader>] :FuzzyFinderFile \*\*\/<CR>
```

Answer (score 1):

Haven't used Textmate, but [LustyExplorer](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1890) could be what you're looking for. Demo [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dLMKVYqdarY).